# gradle publishing jar into maven repository

Tags: java, maven, jar, gradle, publishing

I have a problem when publishing a jar intro a maven repository with install or uploadit to artifactory. Let's assume i have this config :

group = 'com.test' 
  version = '1.1.1-SNAPSHOT'
  baseName = 'test-jar'

When i do gradle install multiple times, the task will install multiple versions in my repository, instead of overwriting the old version. I will have in my repository something like :

test-jar-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT
  test-jar-1.1.1-20140813.095846-1.jar

and so on.

How can i config gradle to install only one version in repository, to remove the timestamp from my jar name, like maven does.

Thx.

Comment: You'd have to provide more details, such as which Gradle version and Maven plugin you use, and which command you use to install to the local repository. Recent Gradle versions shouldn't have this problem.

Comment: I use gradle 1.12, i don't know the maven plugin version.